# Why Controller.Json and Newtonsoft Json return different results?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an anonymouse object which contains a collection of anonymouse objects, but changing it into json differs between `controller's Json` and `Newtonsoft Json` - how can I remove those additional fields from `Json(data)`?

```
var dataFromDb = _context
                 .Users
                 .Select(x => new { x.id, x.name })
                 .ToList();

var data = new { something = true, data = dataFromDb};
```

Result while using Newtonsoft json:

`return StatusCode(200, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));`

```
{
    "something": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "d5696edd-4321-4dba-9eba-c4df3644bb78",
            "name": "XYZ"
        }
    ]
}
```

`return StatusCode(200, Json(data));`

```
{
    "contentType": null,
    "serializerSettings": null,
    "statusCode": null,
    "value":
    {
        "something": true,
        "data": 
        [
            {
                "id": "d5696edd-4321-4dba-9eba-c4df3644bb78",
                "name": "XYZ"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Controller.Json` produces `JsonResult` object, which contains additional parameters. The overview of those can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Whereas Newtonsoft serializes the specified object to a JSON string.

Data wise (that you serialize), they do produce the same result.

---

If you want to append to those properties, it's the normal use of getters and setters on an object:

```
return new JsonResult(result)
{
    StatusCode = 200
};
```

And this object should be returned from the controller instead of `return StatusCode(200, Json(data));`

---

It's also worth pointing out that `Json` is an extension method (helper method) for the JsonResult. They both return the same thing, an instance of `JsonResult` (which in turn inherits `ActionResult`).

Calling `Json` or `JsonResult` is a matter of preference, you'll have to write less for `Json` and won't have to declare instances of `JsonResult` in your controller as it'll be done behind the scenes for you.

Comment: Yeh I was just about to put an answer in about "like for like" but you covered that now. response 1 != response 2 because is one the data as json the other a jsonresult object as json that happens to contain the data.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that setting `StatusCode` as you've done in the example here is redundant. There's also little benefit in creating an instance of `JsonResult` instead of using the `Json` convenience method.

Comment: May also be worth noting that the default ASP.NET JavaScriptSerializer absolutely butchers `DateTime`s and produces something like `"/Date(80912369123875)"` instead of a "standard" ISO-8601 formatted date e.g. `"2022-11-08T16:39:14Z"`